# Reflexivity of the relation between strings over language $L$ defined by $xc \equiv L$ and $yc \equiv L $

Tags: equivalence-relations, formal-languages

> Given any two strings, call them $x$ and $y$, over any language $L$ and given property such that  if $xc \equiv L$ and  $yc \equiv L $ (where $c$ is some string), then $x \equiv y$.

I would like to prove that $\equiv$ is reflexive. I tried $x \equiv x \rightarrow x-x \equiv0$ and $y(0) \rightarrow x(0)\equiv0$ Therefore, $\equiv$ is reflexive.
But somehow I don't feel this is right.  Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There must be some mix-up. Instead of $x,y$ you mean $a,b$? And what does your notation $ac\equiv L$ mean, after all?

Comment: @mathse Yes, sorry I fixed that. the notation means that strings xc and yc are indistinguishable by language L

Comment: Yes, okay, but just as a matter of notational style, should it be something like $x\equiv_L c$?

Comment: @mathse Yes you are right, that would be better style but does what I have as far as the prove make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: Um, rather not. You say $x-x$, how is "$-$" defined on strings?

Comment: Where did you get this question from? Can you try to relate as much information to us as you have been given? I think some assumptions on $\equiv$ are missing ...

Comment: @mathse All I have is if x and y are indistinguishable by L we indicate that with $$x \equiv_L y$$ and with that I am trying to prove that $$\equiv_L$$ is symmetric.

Comment: Symmetric or reflexive? These are different things ...

Comment: @mathse well actually both, but I started with reflexive and tried to prove that it is symmetric with $$yc \equiv xc \rightarrow y \equiv x \rightarrow x \equiv y \rightarrow xc \equiv yc $$, therefore symmetric, but also unsure if I did it right. Also distinguishable is defined as "for some string c, exactly one xc or yc is a member of L".

Comment: Well, I think you should provide all available information for otherwise it makes no sense to reason about this exercise.

Comment: @mathse It basically asks to show that $$\equiv_L$$ is an equivalence relation. So I went about showing reflexive property that is aRa and symmetric if aRb, then bRa and then I will show transitive. This is a hw problem I am working on Intro to Theory of Computation by Sipser number 1.51.

Comment: Alright, the book is online. Why is it that you make so many mistakes in copying this task from the book? I suggest you edit the problem description above, to describe the problem **correctly**.

Comment: @mathse okay I'll do that later, I'm sorry I gotta run now I have class starting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $\equiv_L$ is defined by: $x\equiv_L y$ iff $xz\in L\iff yz\in L$ for all strings $z$.

Clearly, $x\equiv_L x$ since $xz\in L\iff xz\in L$ for all strings $z$.